# Funny Time Dilation Relation

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Today I was curiously calculating/comparing the times of moving observers and the time recorded by a corresponding stationary observer using Einstein's time dilation equation as detailed in Special Relativity. I was just trying to see the relation between the time recorded by the moving observer compared to the stationary one at various fractions of the speed of light. I noticed that the dilation experienced by the stationary observer when 1 second passes for the moving observer are the same values I get when I divide the time passed for the stationary observer by the time passed for the moving observer at different spans of time (i.e 1 hour and 1 year passed for the moving observer)

I'll post a pic of my results below.

[Picture of Excel table for clarification and e.g values](https://i.imgsafe.org/5de56ca.png)

Can anyone tell me the connection between the ratio of time dilation of the moving observer and the stationary observer and the values I'm getting for the time dilation of 1 sec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ratio of $\Delta t_s$ to $\Delta t_r$ is always
$$
\frac{ \Delta t_s }{ \Delta t_r } = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2} } } = \gamma
$$
This is completely independent of what $\Delta t_s$ or $\Delta t_r$ you choose. Also, if you choose $\Delta t_{r_1} = 1$, then $\Delta t_{s_1} = \gamma$. We must therefore have
$$
\Delta t_{s_1} = \frac{ \Delta t_{s_2} }{ \Delta t_{r_2} } = \frac{ \Delta t_{s_3} }{ \Delta t_{r_3} } =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2} } } = \gamma
$$
as you are finding.